# Is there a property to know if an image is vertically or horizontally in Jimp?

Tags: node.js, image

I am making a code to put a watermark on images. The only problem is that some images are in vertical mode and others are in horizontal mode. Due to this, vertically images are cropping in a square and adding a black background arround the square.

I have found nothing. I am using image.composite like this: https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp/issues/175#issuecomment-255878441 but this does not resolve my problem. I resize the image that goes on the background image.

My actual code:

```js
let jimp = require("Jimp")
let images = require("fs").readdirSync("./images")
images.forEach(image => {
    let p1 = jimp.read("./images/"+image.split("/").pop());
    Promise.all([p1, p2]).then(imgs => {
        imgs[1].resize(imgs[0].getWidth() > imgs[0].getHeight() ? imgs[0].getWidth() / 50 * 4.166666666666667 * 1.75 : imgs[0].getHeight() / 50 * 4.166666666666667* 1.75, 
            imgs[0].getWidth() > imgs[0].getHeight() ? imgs[0].getWidth() / 50 * 4.166666666666667 * 1.75 : imgs[0].getHeight() / 50 * 4.166666666666667* 1.75, 
            () => {
                imgs[0].composite(imgs[1], imgs[0].HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_RIGHT, imgs[0].VERTICAL_ALIGN_BOTTOM).write("./outputs/"+image.split("/").pop());
            }
        )
    }).catch(console.error)
})
```

This works well on horizontal images but not on vertical.
Any help is appreciated.

Edit: I found that jimp read verticals images as horizontals. I don't know if canvas can do this better.

Comment: I can't find a convenient way to do it with _jimp_, but you could use [node-exif](https://github.com/gomfunkel/node-exif) package to read exif orientation data.

Comment: Finally, i have done it with two folder and canvas but i will see if node exif is better

Answer (score 1):

You can use the img.bitmap.width & img.bitmap.height property in JIMP to get the actual width and height of the image.

```
const width = item.bitmap.width
const height = item.bitmap.height
if (width > height) 
// horizontal
else if (width == height) 
// square
else
// vertical
```

Based on this you can proceed further on the logic